# My wifi is not working

Tags: drivers, wireless

my computer does not appear available wifi network connection.
To solve this, I try install the driver rtl8723be, but not worked!

I saw the following [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).
He suggest execute the following command:

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&   chmod +x wireless-info &&   ./wireless-info`

that generate the file 'wireless-info.txt' follows such file:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/mwQRtHQBSH/

When I execute

`sudo modprobe rtl8723be && sudo dmesg | grep 8723`
appears:

```
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not 
 available
```

Please how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be && sudo dmesg | grep 8723` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I edited!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Is it necessary Disable Secure Boot to work?

Comment: Yes when you aren't using the kernel module, it must be something you downloaded and compiled

Comment: From your paste: "Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS" This version reached end of life on April 30, 2021. Please install a supported version.